# Activating Smarty

Tags: civimail, smarty

I'm trying to send end of year tax letters to donors. I want to customize the letters/emails with their total donation amount for the whole year. I understand I need to activate "smarty" to be able to do this, however, I can't find where  this needs to be configured or enabled.

any guidelines would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to StackExchnage Aida. Activating smarty is usually done in the file civicrm.settings.php.

However for what you have in mind you may want to take a look at the extension "[Summary Fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields)". It prvides certain information / data such as the total contribution amount in custom contact fields which allows you to easily use them in emails or letters.

Comment: The setting in civicrm.settings.php is 
 if (!defined('CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY', 1 );